# wordpress site lost style/css when visited from the domain but okay when visited from IP address

Tags: wordpress, apache, dns, hosting, digital-ocean

I recently installed openlitespeed wordpress on one droplet and configured the domain/listener/SSL etc according to [its documentation](https://docs.litespeedtech.com/Cloud/wordpress/?utm_source=DigitalOcean&utm_medium=Email_Internal&utm_campaign=OpenLiteSpeedWP_Welcome#step-4). When I visit the site thru IP address, it looks fine. But when I visit the site thru the domains, things are weird:
when visited from the ip: [206.189.134.87](http://206.189.134.87), and the domain with `www`: [www.gudianjita.xyz](http://www.gudianjita.xyz), the site is not secure but the style is fine. when visited from the domain [gudianjita.xyz](http://gudianjita.xyz), the site is secure but the style/css are gone.

I am not sure what had happened. If anyone can give me some plausible reasons to check into, that will be great. Also, if additional information about any settings can be helpful to debug, I would be happy to share. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you installed your wp using the ip address. So the values of `site_url` and `home_url` options in the wp_options table are `206.189.134.87`.

You can change it by updating the rows in wp_options table or just add these lines to the `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://gudianjita.xyz' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://gudianjita.xyz' );
```

Goodluck

Comment: Hi Ali, thanks! I made the changes as you suggested but seems nothing is happening. Do I need to restart the wordpress service? If yes, how could I do that?

Comment: After adding these two lines, I couldn't open the `wp-admin` page anymore. I had to remove these two lines...